# Base64 image not showing in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, base64

I've got a Base64 encoded image and it's showing correctly in all browsers (even in Edge) except in internet-explorer.

I've already read similar questions/answers where the base64 encoded image isn't allowed to be bigger than 32KB or missing the /png at start. I've got both covered (length of base64 string is 3330 characters and ending with "==" so with the formula size = (length * (3/4) - 2) i am getting a file size of approx. 2400 bytes which should be okay.

Image example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeZadO#anon-login

`<img alt="QR Code" src="data:image/png;base64,......==">`

I appreciate any suggestion i could try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured using percentage width on my container element was the problem. Looks like IE cannot calculate the width properly; setting a min-width on my img-tag solved the problem!

Comment: I suggest that you coud mark your answer as solution if it solved your problem, and this will be helpful for someone meets with the same problem.

Comment: thanks! i just did it; i totally forgot about marking it on the weekend. thank you for reminding me!